# Flask, how to return value, after processing data got from input form

Tags: python, web-applications, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to use Flask to create webapp;

dicrectory tree is like this:

online_service:
----app:
--------forms.py
--------**init**.py
--------templates: 
------------index.html
------------login.html
--------views.py
----run.py

And:
run.py:

```
import os
import sys 
from app import app 
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'any string'
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port = 8889)
```

views.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect
from app import app
from .forms import LoginForm

file_dir = os.path.split(os.path.realpath(__file__))[0]
os.chdir(file_dir)
cur_dir = os.getcwd()
back_end_dir = os.path.join(cur_dir, "./../../back_end")
sys.path.append(back_end_dir)
import main

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')

def index():
    return render_template("index.html",
        title = 'Home')

def process(url):
    url_status = "Invalid"
    res = ""           
    res = main.get_life_stage(url)
    url_str = "Url: " + url
    url_status = "valid"
    url_status_str = "Url_status: " + url_status
    ret_str = "\n".join([url_str, url_status_str, res])
    return ret_str


@app.route('/search', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        url = form.openid.data
        ret_str = ""
        ret = process(url)
        flash(ret_str)
        return redirect('/index')
    return render_template('login.html',
        title = 'Sign In',
        form = form)
```

In views.py, ret = process(url) processes data from the front, then return a string, ret = process(url) works well in unit test, but not in views

So, how to show return string of process function?
Any hints, I'll appreciate it.
Thanks!

Comment: remove `redirect` and  use `ret` with some `render_template`

Comment: or maybe you should `flash(ret)` instead of `flash(ret_str)`and then use it with template in `index()`

Comment: Thanks，replace redirect('/index') with  render_template('*.html', *,*), then fix it. I don't know how it works, but it works!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should assign to `ret_str`

```
ret_str = process(url)
```

because you use `flash(ret_str)`

-

I hope you use this flashed message in template in `index()`